# wget multiple PDF files from links

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, pdf, download

I would like to download PDF files for particular search terms from the CIA archives. For example for "Vietnam", the URL is https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/search/site/Vietnam.

The PDF files can viewed after clicking each link, is it possible to download the PDF files programatically by modifying `wget -A pdf https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/search/site/Vietnam`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help!

First, store all the download files or URLs in a text file as:

$ cat > download-file-list.txt

URL1

URL2

URL3

URL4

echo "Enter text"

text=$1

cat URLs.txt | grep -i $text > /tmp/new.txt

wget -i /tmp/new.txt

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The issue is there are *2422* pages of search results for Vietnam with *48,423* links. The PDF for each link can be viewed after clicking each link. e.g. for the first link, the URL is  [link](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/document/loc-hak-252-10-5-5)